# redis UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: command_obj.callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

Simple nodejs and redis code to set data into redis
when i use `client.set(key,value)` it works perfectly
but when i use `hset` like so:

```
const fields = [ 'partnerId', '1404798351','myId','23423423' ] //this is a simple example

const client = createClient({ url: process.env.REDIS_URL });
client.hset(`chat:252353453`, ...fields)
```

it returns this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: command_obj.callback is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

`hset` expects a [specific set of arguments](https://github.com/simplegeo/nodejs-redis#usage):

`client.hset("hash key", "hashtest 1", "some value", redis.print);`

The hash key, the key to set within the hash, the value we're setting, and an optional callback.

You can't set an arbitrary number of key/value pairs as you're attempting to do. The library is seeing your 4th argument (`'myId'`) and treating it as a function, which causes the error.

Comment: I tried to set only 3 arguments `'chat:2342','partnerId', '566571423'`
the hash key, the key to set within it and the value...

it returns same error message

Comment: What version of the 'redis' npm package are you using?

Comment: I use '3.1.2'
redis:3.1.2